# Msys2 in windows 10 with GTK return error pkg-config

Tags: msys2, pkg-config

hi guys i try to run Msys2 and GTK in windows 10 i follow this installation
https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows
when i'am arrived at step 5 ,pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain base-devel , i install all packet
i tested installation , but return me:
gcc -o  main.c -pthread `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
bash: gcc: command not found
i add in my windows envairoment variable in the system this path
PKG_CONFIG_PATH
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig
and  i insert in all  my .bashrc
this code export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
but nothing return me always the same error
anyone can help me  ? or have some suggestions , thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [instructions you linked to](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows) say to install the `mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3` package.  That is a package for the 64-bit MinGW environment provided by MSYS2.  Therefore, to use it, you must start MSYS2 by running mingw64.exe from the MSYS2 installation directory, or using the corresopnding shortcut in your start menu.  You can type `echo $MSYSTEM` and if it returns `MINGW64` then you are using the right environemnt.  You should not need to edit `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` yourself in your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

In case this might help you or somebody else: I've had the same problem happen in a build using MSYS2 - not for GTK3 but for a bunch of different libraries. The `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` was definitely exported correctly and its path was also correct but `pkg-config` would stubbornly search in its default search paths instead of the ones provided outside of the MSYS2 install. I tried `export`ing the variable and setting it through the `.bashrc` file but that got me nowhere.

I'm not fully sure why it works but, reading through some old company internal docs, I read that installing the `dos2unix` utility automagically fixed the problem and it did work for me. Install it using `pacman -S dos2unix`. You might want to update your package list first with `pacman -Syu` to have up to date packages.